# How can I validate an installation DVD?

Tags: installation, virtualbox, disk, iso, checksums

I have downloaded an Ubuntu ISO and burned it to DVD. While installing from the DVD onto VirtualBox I got an error which suggested either the HDD or DVD or overheating were the cause. I am investigating all three. How can I verify that the DVD has been correctly burned (I still have the original ISO file)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the installation DVD loads, for a while your should see a image with a hand and a keyboard at the bottom.

[image]

Press any key while this image is showing and a menu with the installation options will open. You will find there an option to check the media.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

How to check the MD5SUM https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM

Ubuntu Hashs https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes

This should give you the information needed to verify the .ISO