# Ubuntu 16.04 hangs at boot

Tags: hardware, asus, iwlwifi

Ubuntu 16.04 wont boot and hangs at "unsupported splx structure"

Im on a Asus ROG 501JW, with Skylake CPU, Intel 530 + Nvidia 960m and intel wireless AC-7265
[image: This is what the console puts out before the systems hangs/freezes]

Comment: It isn't a wireless issue, look at all the ext4 messages, may be something corrupt in the file system

Comment: True, it might not be - but when booting from a Live USB the very second the little LED in the f2 key (indication that wifi is on) lights up the system freezes, leading to my assumption that it is indeed the wifi card that somehow crash the system. I might not be though :/ I'm patiently waiting for now :(

Comment: I have Intel wifi and see the unsupported splx structure in dmesg and it doesn't cause any issues for me.  Any chance you are dual boot with win 10 and haven't disabled hybrid shutdown?

Comment: I have tried now to disable fast boot or hybrid shutdown like described here http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html - am i missing something?

Comment: You might have to reinstall Ubuntu to get it straightened out, windows hybrid shutdown doesn't unmount the hard drive and this led to some issues in 15.10

Comment: I'm currently trying to get it to work on a live session - but that might be the issue itself then..

Comment: If the error is from the Live session, the download may have been corrupted

Comment: Will try again and report back - thank you for the help btw!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I validate an installation DVD?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/110463/how-can-i-validate-an-installation-dvd)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using these boot parameters to boot 16.04 on my GL552VW:
i915.preliminary_hw_support=1 nouveau.modeset=0 acpi_osi=! acpi=0 acpi_backlight=vendor idle=nomwait

My touchpad requires me to boot twice to get the pointer to display. I am trying to figure that out.

Modify 10_linux in /etc/grub.d line 177 put in after ro and before ${arg} and then sudo update-grub in a terminal window

Comment: Will try this when i get home!

Comment: I have not tried this but.... I tried installing the nvidia proprietary driver on a USB with a "save changes" partion so it would save my changes in the Live session, and after installing the Nvidia driver the computer now boots, and everything seems to two work expect the stuff highlighted by Jon Delano above :) I'm guessing the boot parameters above work.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried what Jon Delano posted above but... I tried installing the nvidia proprietary driver on a USB with a "save changes" partion so it would save my changes in the Live session, and after installing the Nvidia driver the computer now boots, and everything seems to two work expect the stuff highlighted by Jon Delano above :) I'm guessing the boot parameters above work as well - It seems in the end its a problem with the nouveau driver..