# Ubuntu liveusb hangs after creating slice

Tags: live-usb

Title says it all~

Got a new laptop, but booting off the livecd hangs.
Here's a picture of where it happens.

[image: screenshot]

I've tested my ram, it seems ok.

Any ideas?

Comment: Tried booting using some troubleshooting options? Depending on how you created the live usb, there may be a nice GUI menu showing boot options to try, like nomodeset, noapic, nolapic, etc. And I like to remove the "splash" option too, to always see the messages instead of the graphical "ubuntu + dots" picture

Comment: @Xen2050 I've done nomodeset and the noapic options. Nothing changes. However, I've figured out if I wait five or so minutes, I get "unsupported splx structure"

Comment: Googling "unsupported splx structure" gives [another Q right on this site](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760569/ubuntu-16-04-hangs-at-boot) (maybe a duplicate of this Q, if it's answers work ;-) suggesting to try either these boot options: `i915.preliminary_hw_support=1 nouveau.modeset=0 acpi_osi=! acpi=0 acpi_backlight=vendor idle=nomwait` or installing the proprietary video driver for your computer, maybe Nvidia? It doesn't sound like you can boot that computer at all yet, and if the usb doesn't save changes (persistent) than trying the boot options above would be plan A.

Comment: I'll give it a shot once I can! Unfortunately I'm having hardware issues now.